# ggplot2 reverse order of scale_brewer

Tags: r, ggplot2

Seemingly a very simple thing to do but it took me >30min without finding answer.

How do I reverse the order of colors?  By looking at [documentation for scale_brewer](http://www.had.co.nz/ggplot2/scale_brewer.html), i figured it can be `formatter=` argument being suspicious.  I passed `'rev'` and then `rev`, but they have no effect (no error message, just ignored).

Comment: pbaylis's answer (set ``direction=-1``) seems to be the simplest answer to the question in the title, but joran's or Josh's give more control, e.g. passing an arbitrary sequence of colors, not just the reverse one.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

I think you probably want to select the colors using `brewer.pal` directly and then use `scale_colour_manual`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(RColorBrewer)

ggplot(mtcars,aes(x = mpg, y = disp)) + 
    geom_point(aes(colour = factor(cyl))) + 
    scale_colour_manual(values = rev(brewer.pal(3, "BuPu")))
```

Then you can `rev` the order of the colors there.

As of version 2.0,0 of ggplot there is now a more direct way to do this, see the answer by @pbaylis below.

Comment: +1 -- This is nice.  It might also be good to 'hardwire' in the number of colors needed, like this: `rev(brewer.pal(n=length(unique(mtcars$cyl)), "BuPu"))`.

Comment: ...or `scale_fill_manual` whichever paradigm is most appropriate for your geom.

Comment: Feel free to update your answer with the code I posted and I'll remove mine for clarity.

Comment: This solution works when using `library(RColorBrewer)`. (I know OP knows this already, but I wanted to swap ggplot colors and didn't know this.)

Answer (score 100):

The CRAN version of ggplot2 now allows users to specify `direction=-1` in [scale_brewer](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/scale_brewer.html) to reverse the colors. The following produces the same plot as the accepted answer.

```
ggplot(mtcars,aes(x = mpg, y = disp)) + 
  geom_point(aes(colour = factor(cyl))) + 
  scale_colour_brewer(palette="BuPu", direction=-1)
```

Comment: Up! More direct than do the `rev(...)`

Comment: Didn't work for me. Not sure why. Is it because I use Mac ?

Comment: I have R v3.6.1, ggplot2 v3.2.1, RColorBrewer v1.1.2 on MacOS Mojave v10.14.6 and this works perfectly!

Answer (score 33):

This will not help with the OP's problem - I know. For discrete scales like `scale_..._brewer()`, doing `scale_..._manual(values = rev(colorsYouHad))` is the right answer.

Nevertheless, for **continuous** scales, you can simply pass:

`scale_..._...(..., trans = "reverse")`

e.g., for the continuous equivalent of `scale_..._brewer()`:

`scale_..._distiller("My Scale", palette = "Spectral", trans = "reverse")`

Comment: I appreciate the desire to alert users to a now simpler way to do the same thing, but since both answers _do_ work, an edit calling a different answer the "correct" one is inappropriate. I am quite responsive to comments on my answers. A simple comment telling me my answer is out of date is sufficient.

Comment: This is a nice, simple answer, worked for me, thanks!

Comment: Note that while using `trans = "reverse"` , also the order of the values changes. For continuous scales, this means that the legend values will _decrease_ upward

Comment: @joran, this answer was *not* solving the OP's problem and hence was not doing 'the same thing'. This is why I submitted a different answer.

Comment: FWIW if you are trying to plot significance values (i.e. working with probabilities) this really helps, in connection with changing the direction (which is -1 by default in the continuous case, for some reasons). E.g. `scale_fill_distiller(palette = "YlOrRd", direction = 1, na.value = "gray", trans="reverse", name="Significance")`

Comment: @Lennert did you find any way to rectify this? I'm having this exact issue right now.

Comment: For anyone reading my query, try using `direction="horizontal"` in the scale continous function instead of `trans="reverse"`.

Answer (score 11):

If you don't want to muck around directly with `RColorBrewer` (a lovely package), you can reverse the levels of the factor in the original data.frame, and then plot it:

```
dsamp <- diamonds[sample(nrow(diamonds), 1000), ] 

# Reverse the levels of the factor associated with color, here 'clarity'
# (Might be safer to assign this to a new column named, e.g., 'clarity2')
levels(dsamp$clarity) <- rev(levels(dsamp$clarity))

d <- qplot(carat, price, data = dsamp, colour = clarity)
d + scale_colour_brewer(breaks = levels(dsamp$clarity))
```

And if you want to print the key in the same order as before the reversal, just do this:

```
d + scale_colour_brewer(breaks = rev(levels(dsamp$clarity)))
```

Answer (score 4):

I know, very late to the party.  But I ran into this problem a while back and used the above solution. I'm currently going through r4ds by Hadley Wickham and there is a ridiculously easy solution so I thought I'd post it.  Change this:

```
ggplot(mtcars,aes(x = mpg, y = disp)) + 
geom_point(aes(colour = factor(cyl)))
```

to this:

```
ggplot(mtcars,aes(x = mpg, y = disp)) + 
geom_point(aes(colour = factor(-cyl))) #note the minus symbol
```

Answer (score 1):

I get an error saying the minus sign is not applicable for factors. I'm working with greyscale rather than brewer, perhaps that is the source of the error? For scale_color_grey, I found reversing the start and end points from the default worked.

```
# lighter shade for first category (default)
+ scale_color_grey(start = 0.2, end = 0.8) 

# darker shade for first category 
+ scale_color_grey(start = 0.8, end = 0.2)
```