# How to select colors from a predefined color set in ggplot2

Tags: r, colors, plot, ggplot2, color-palette

Suppose that I have a dataset like the following:

```
set.seed(1)
dataset <- data.frame(x = sort(rnorm(100)), 
                      y = sort(rlnorm(100))+1:4, 
                      group=rep(letters[1:4], 25))
```

I would like to create a plot using `ggplot2`. Instead of choosing colors manually, I use the pre-defined color set `Paired`:

```
ggplot(dataset, aes(x = x, colour = group)) + 
geom_line(aes(y=y)) + 
scale_colour_brewer(palette="Paired")
```

I get the plot as shown below: the data points for groups `a` and `b` are in two shades of blue, whereas the data points for groups `c` and `d` are in two shades of green.

[image]

Suppose now, I would like to only plot the data corresponding to groups `c` and `d`, and I would like to use the two shades of green. If I simply do the following:

```
ggplot(dataset[dataset$group %in% c("c", "d"),], aes(x = x, colour = group)) + 
geom_line(aes(y=y)) + 
scale_colour_brewer(palette="Paired")
```

the function will automatically select the two shades of blue (see below), since they come first in the `Paired` palette set.

[image]

#### So my question is: how can I select colors in a pre-defined color set when I use `ggplot2`

Comment: You do it using scale_*_manual but passing in a specific subset of the colors from `brewer_pal`.

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but this should give you the idea: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8751004/324364

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
require(RColorBrewer)
ggplot(dataset[dataset$group %in% c("c", "d"),], aes(x = x, colour = group)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y=y)) + 
  scale_colour_manual(values = brewer.pal(4, "Paired")[3:4])
```

[image]

For a more scalable approach, define the palette globally, outside of the plotting code. You will then be able to dynamically map the subsetted data to the corresponding colour.