# Unused argument direction = -1 in scale_fill_brewer()

Tags: r, ggplot2, colorbrewer

I am creating some plots with **R** and **ggplot2**, and everything works as expected except by chosing the palette. My intention is to use one of the supplied with brewer but **reversed**, i.g. the colours of the palette backwards.

```
p <- ggplot(data=df, aes(x=age, y=patients, fill=factor(age))) + geom_bar(stat="identity")+ scale_fill_brewer(type = "seq", palette = "RdYlGn", direction = -1) 
p <- p + theme_classic() + theme(panel.background = element_blank(), panel.grid.major=element_blank(), panel.grid.minor=element_blank())
```

Following the instructions from the [ggplot manual](http://docs.ggplot2.org/dev/scale_brewer.html), the parameter **direction set to -1 should do the trick** and reverse the colours order. However, when running the code, R complains about the parameter saying it was unused as it was unexpected.

> Error in discrete_scale("fill", "brewer", brewer_pal(type, palette),
>   ...) :  unused argument (direction = -1)

Any ideas what am I missing?

Comment: Those are docs for the bleeding-edge-soon-to-be-released version of ggplot2. There is no `direction` parameter for the current ggplot2 package on CRAN. In general, `help(function_name)` is a better way to ensure you are looking at documentation for what you are using than web searches. Reference [this SO q&a](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8750871/ggplot2-reverse-order-of-scale-brewer) for reversing colorbrewer scales manually (before the impending release) or install the github version of ggplot2.

Comment: Thank you! Haven't noticed the package reference version.